# Returning result of an async operation with a Node.js web server

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Express to build a web API. In the following example, SVG data is converted to PNG and uploaded to S3.

```
const svg2png = require("svg2png");
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

app.post('/svg_to_png', function (req, res) {

  let params = req.body

  // STEP 1: Convert SVG to PNG:
  var outputBuffer = svg2png.sync(params.svg_data, {});

  // STEP 2: Upload to S3:
  let s3_params = {
      Bucket:params.bucket,
      Key:params.key,
      Body:outputBuffer,
      ContentType:'image/png',
      ContentDisposition:'inline',
      ACL: 'public-read'
  }
  result = s3.putObject(s3_params,function(err,data){
      if (err){
        return err;
      }
      return 'success';
  });

  // Return Image URL:
  let image_url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/' + params.bucket + '/' + params.key
  res.send(image_url)

})
```

I want the API to respond with the URL of the converted image, which the requesting client can then immediately download. The problem is, the S3 upload operation is async, and so when the response is delivered, the image does not yet exist at the URL location, forcing the client to poll for its existence.

Is there a way to get the web server to respond only once the S3 upload has completed?

Comment: in the putObject callback, just call `res.body(....).end()`

Comment: @Brandon that worked - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this :

```
const putObjPromise = s3.putObject(params).promise();
putObjPromise
  .then(data => {
    // Return the URL here.
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

AWS has this doc for Promises : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

as @Brandon mentioned, you can return the response once the s3 callback is completed. You can also use `s3.putObject(params).promise()`. I prefer this since it improves readability.

```
app.post('/svg_to_png', async function (req, res) {

  let params = req.body
  ...
  // STEP 2: Upload to S3:
  let params = {
      ...
  }

  try {
    const result = await s3.putObject(params).promise();
    // Return Image URL:
    // image_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/' + params.bucket + '/' + params.key

    // res.body(....).end()

  } catch(err) {
    // return error response
  }
})
```

Comment: For some reason this results in an hanging request that never responds.

Comment: Please post your current code. So that I can have a look.

Comment: Also what's your node version. Async/await only supported from node 8

Comment: SEE: https://gist.github.com/ykessler/01fc02a598c8b43830db69dd16b4ba02. Node 12

Comment: declared the `result` variable, updated my answer. if it doesn't help, can you send me the crash log, thank you

Comment: Still hanging. There's no error or output, it just doesn't respond to the request. I suspect using `async function` as a callback for the action handler will not work.

Comment: I thought you are happy with the other answer. Let me know if you want me to have a look.